# Import type "Request" from express-request-id

Tags: typescript, express, types

In our TypeScript-based web app with express, we added the npm package [express-request-id](https://github.com/floatdrop/express-request-id) for decorating our HTTP Requests and responses with X-Request-Id headers.

We defined a middleware for setting the request's `id` also in the HTTP response header roughly as follows:

```
import type { Request, NextFunction, RequestHandler, Response } from 'express'
//...
export const requestIdHandler = (_fn: RequestHandler) => (req: Request, res: Response, _next: NextFunction) => {
    res.set('X-Request-Id', req.id)
}
```

As expected, this does not type, since the property `id`is not defined in the type that comes from express. We've noticed that the [types.d.ts](https://github.com/floatdrop/express-request-id/blob/master/types.d.ts) file in express-request-id overrides the type definition of the `Request` type as defined by express, but we did not manage to import that type. What is the correct way to import the overriden type?

Comment: They seem to declare a global namespace called `Express`, so have you tried the to type your variable like `req:Express.Request`? You may need to import the express-request-id types like `import express-request-id` for the namespace to be available.

Comment: @Ben thank you for your help! Unfortunately, when I add the import and type the variable as you suggested, I receive the error ```'Express' is not defined. eslint no-undef```. Problem seems to be that the overriden type is not exported?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand the way they declare their types. It feels very hacky but I'm not proficient enough to propose another workaround :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/#adding-custom-properties-to-the-request-type): we need to extend the interface defined by express, by adding a declaration file `src/types/express/index.d.ts` with the following content:

```
// src/types/express/index.d.ts

// to make the file a module and avoid the TypeScript error
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      id?: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Then TypeScript's [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) mechanism will fuse the two declarations into one.